# Does the new C++ Standard provide new containers?

Tags: c++, stl

With C++ STL being updated, will there ever be a set number of containers.
**Edit:**  When it comes to containers,  Will there be new addition to the library in addition vectors, lists etc..

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking. Do you mean will the C++ STandard Library ever cease being added to?

Comment: I am reading your "Preparing for the next C++ standard" i wait.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The proposed C++ Standard (aka C++0x) adds the following templated containers:

- `array`  (rather like a fixed size vector)
- `forward_list`     (singly-linked list)
- `unordered_map` and `unordered_multimap`  (hash table as dictionary)
- `unordered_set` and `unordered_multiset`  (hash table as set)

Answer (score 1):

You might take a look at [Hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Hash_tables) section of a very good Wikipedia article on C++0x